# Redux-Saga error in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, redux, saga

I've created an application using React Native and want to fetch data from API using redux-saga. 

Everything works fine before I configured my redux and sagas.

Here are the I added and modified :

ReactRestoRedux.js

```js
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

// Categories types
const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    categories: null,
    categoriesSucceed: ['payload'],
    categoriesFailed: null
})

export const ReactRestoTypes = Types
export default Creators

// Initial state
export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
    payload: null,
    errorMessage: null,
    fetchCategories: false
})

// Reducers
export const categoriesRequest = (state) => 
    state.merge({ fetchCategories: true })

export const categoriesRequestSucceed = (state, action) => {
    const { payload } = action
    return state.merge({ fetchCategories: false, errorMessage: null, payload})
}

export const categoriesRequestFailed = (state) =>
    state.merge({ fetchCategories: false, errorMessage: true})

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
    [Types.CATEGORIES_REQUEST]: categoriesRequest,
    [Types.CATEGORIES_SUCCEED]: categoriesRequestSucceed,
    [Types.CATEGORIES_FAILED]: categoriesRequestFailed
})
```

index.js (redux)

```js
import { takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
//import API from '../Services/Api'
import FixtureAPI from '../Services/FixtureApi'
import DebugConfig from '../Config/DebugConfig'
import ZomatoAPI from '../Services/ZomatoAPI'

/* ------------- Types ------------- */

import { StartupTypes } from '../Redux/StartupRedux'
import { GithubTypes } from '../Redux/GithubRedux'
import { ReactRestoTypes } from '../Redux/ReactRestoRedux'

/* ------------- Sagas ------------- */

import { startup } from './StartupSagas'
import { getUserAvatar } from './GithubSagas'
import { getCategories } from './ReactRestoSagas'

/* ------------- API ------------- */

// The API we use is only used from Sagas, so we create it here and pass along
// to the sagas which need it.
const api = DebugConfig.useFixtures ? FixtureAPI : ZomatoAPI.create()

/* ------------- Connect Types To Sagas ------------- */

export default function * root () {
  yield all([
    // some sagas only receive an action
    takeLatest(StartupTypes.STARTUP, startup),

    // some sagas receive extra parameters in addition to an action
    takeLatest(GithubTypes.USER_REQUEST, getUserAvatar, api),

    takeLatest(ReactRestoTypes.CATEGORIES_REQUEST, getCategories)
  ])
}
```

ReactRestoSagas.js

```js
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { path } from 'ramda'
import ReacRestoActions from '../Redux/ReactRestoRedux'
import ReactRestoAPI from '../Services/ZomatoAPI'

const api = ReactRestoAPI.create()

export function* getCategories(){
    const response = yield call(api.getCategories)
    if(response.ok){
        //ok, call action from redux
        yield put(ReacRestoActions.categoriesSucceed(payload))
    }else{
        yield put(ReacRestoActions.categoriesFailed())
    }
}
```

index.js(saga)

```js
import { takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
//import API from '../Services/Api'
import FixtureAPI from '../Services/FixtureApi'
import DebugConfig from '../Config/DebugConfig'
import ZomatoAPI from '../Services/ZomatoAPI'

/* ------------- Types ------------- */

import { StartupTypes } from '../Redux/StartupRedux'
import { GithubTypes } from '../Redux/GithubRedux'
import { ReactRestoTypes } from '../Redux/ReactRestoRedux'

/* ------------- Sagas ------------- */

import { startup } from './StartupSagas'
import { getUserAvatar } from './GithubSagas'
import { getCategories } from './ReactRestoSagas'

/* ------------- API ------------- */

// The API we use is only used from Sagas, so we create it here and pass along
// to the sagas which need it.
const api = DebugConfig.useFixtures ? FixtureAPI : ZomatoAPI.create()

/* ------------- Connect Types To Sagas ------------- */

export default function * root () {
  yield all([
    // some sagas only receive an action
    takeLatest(StartupTypes.STARTUP, startup),

    // some sagas receive extra parameters in addition to an action
    takeLatest(GithubTypes.USER_REQUEST, getUserAvatar, api),

    takeLatest(ReactRestoTypes.CATEGORIES_REQUEST, getCategories)
  ])
}
```

Then I got this error :
[image]

I hope I can get any help for this, been stuck here for hours

Comment: please fix your `index.js(saga)` code in the question. It is same as `ReactRestoSagas.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `ReactRestoRedux.js`.

```
const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    categories: null,
    categoriesSucceed: ['payload'],
    categoriesFailed: null
})
```

doesn't match with

```
export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
    [Types.CATEGORIES_REQUEST]: categoriesRequest,
    [Types.CATEGORIES_SUCCEED]: categoriesRequestSucceed,
    [Types.CATEGORIES_FAILED]: categoriesRequestFailed
})
```

you have modify `categories` key to `categoriesRequest`, like below

```
const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    categoriesRequest: null,
    categoriesSucceed: ['payload'],
    categoriesFailed: null
})
```

Refrence: https://github.com/infinitered/reduxsauce#createactions

Comment: thank you....now I got another error..It say `undefined is not a function (evaluating'_ZomatoAPI2.default.create()')`